# How to deploy application on servers running websockets without terminating client sessions?

Tags: websocket, web-deployment

I am working on designing a large scale web application that will heavily use WebSockets to communicate data between the client browser and our servers.  The question that I have is how we are going to push application updates on our servers without our clients knowing that this is being done.  We want to have as mush as 100% up time as possible.

The problem is with the WebSockets becoming closed if there is an application update being done on it.  Is there a way to hand off an existing connection to another application server?

I was considering to implement some client side script that would automatically re-connect to the server if it was closed prematurely.  However I would like to know from you smart people what other ideas that I can consider.

Thanks!